# Store user agents in mysql database with php

Tags: php, mysql, database, structure

I am successfully trying to store statistics in a mysql database. I made a tracker class which checks the URL and updates the hits in the mysql row 'hits'. However i want to expand my stats with more info like browser /os stuff like that. Now whenever i have a request to my tracker i make a new entry in my user_agents database and i was wondering if this is wise, and how my database structure should be built instead.

I need to mention that the statistics are for different users, so user-x has it's own hits and browser info, and user-y also.

Mysql Database Structure

```
    == lumbr_stats

    |//**id**//|bigint(20)|Nee|
    |active|int(11)|Nee|
    |account|varchar(255)|Nee|
    |date|datetime|Nee|
    |ip|varchar(255)|Nee|
    |hits|bigint(20)|Nee|
    |theme|bigint(20)|Nee|

    == lumbr_themes
    |//**id**//|bigint(20)|Nee|
    |active|int(11)|Nee|
    |slug|varchar(255)|Ja|NULL
    |name|varchar(255)|Nee|
    |description|text|Ja|NULL


    == lumbr_user_agents
    |//**id**//|bigint(20)|Nee|
    |name|varchar(255)|Nee|
    |version|int(11)|Nee|
    |stat_user|bigint(20)|Nee|
```

Tracker class .php

```
    <?php 
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/inc/database.php');
    require_once(__DIR__ . '/lib/KLogger.php');

    Class ThemeStatsTracker
    {
        public $log;

        private $theme_name;
        private $theme_user;
        private $theme_name_db_id;
        private $theme_user_db_id;

        public function __construct()
        {
            // Setup Log 
            $this->log = KLogger::instance(dirname(__FILE__).'/log/', KLogger::DEBUG);

            // Process URI variables
            $uri = explode('/',$_SERVER['REQUEST_URI']);    
            $this->theme_name = (!empty($uri[1])) ? $uri[1] : NULL;
            $this->theme_user = (!empty($uri[2])) ? $uri[2] : NULL;

            // Handle the Request
            $this->database_connect();
            if($this->validate_theme()){
                if($this->user_entry_exists()){
                    $this->user_entry_update(); 
                }else{
                    $this->user_entry_create();
                }   
            }

            // Always serve an image as response
            $this->serve_image();
        }

        private function validate_theme()
        {
            $query  = sprintf("SELECT id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."themes WHERE slug='%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($this->theme_name));
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' Theme name ' . $this->theme_name . ' NOT found');
                return FALSE;
            }else{
                $this->log->logInfo(__FUNCTION__ . ' Theme name ' . $this->theme_name . ' found');
                $this->theme_name_db_id = mysql_result($result,0);
                return TRUE;
            }
        }

        private function user_entry_exists()
        {
            $query  = sprintf("SELECT id FROM ".DB_PREFIX."stats WHERE account='%s' LIMIT 1", mysql_real_escape_string($this->theme_user));
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }
            if(mysql_num_rows($result)==0){
                $this->log->logInfo(__FUNCTION__ . ' New user ' . $this->theme_user);
                return FALSE;
            }else{
                $this->log->logInfo(__FUNCTION__ . ' Existing user ' . $this->theme_user);
                $this->theme_user_db_id = mysql_result($result,0);
                return TRUE;
            }   
        }

        private function user_entry_create()
        {
            $query  = sprintf("INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."stats (id,active,account,date,ip,hits,theme) VALUES ('','1','%s',NOW(),'".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."','1','".$this->theme_name_db_id."')", mysql_real_escape_string($this->theme_user));
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            $insertid = mysql_insert_id();

            if (!$result){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }

            $browser = $this->detect_browser();
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."user_agents (id,name,version,stat_user) VALUES ('','".$browser['name']."','".$browser['version']."','".$insertid."')";

            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            if (!$result2){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query2 . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }

            $this->log->logNotice(__FUNCTION__ . ' New user created with id  ' . mysql_insert_id());
            return TRUE;
        }

        private function user_entry_update()
        {
            $query  = sprintf("UPDATE ".DB_PREFIX."stats SET date=NOW(),ip='".$_SERVER['REMOTE_ADDR']."',hits=hits+1 WHERE id='".$this->theme_user_db_id."' LIMIT 1");
            $result = mysql_query($query);
            if (!$result){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }

            $browser = $this->detect_browser();
            $query2 = "INSERT INTO ".DB_PREFIX."user_agents (id,name,version,stat_user) VALUES ('','".$browser['name']."','".$browser['version']."','".$this->theme_user_db_id."')";

            $result2 = mysql_query($query2);
            if (!$result2){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query2 . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }

            $this->log->logNotice(__FUNCTION__ . ' User with id ' . $this->theme_user_db_id . 'updated');
            return TRUE;
        }

        private function serve_image()
        {
            header("Content-type: image/gif");
            header("Content-length: 43");
            $fp = fopen("php://output","wb");
            fwrite($fp,"GIF89a\x01\x00\x01\x00\x80\x00\x00\xFF\xFF",15);
            fwrite($fp,"\xFF\x00\x00\x00\x21\xF9\x04\x01\x00\x00\x00\x00",12);
            fwrite($fp,"\x2C\x00\x00\x00\x00\x01\x00\x01\x00\x00\x02\x02",12);
            fwrite($fp,"\x44\x01\x00\x3B",4);
            fclose($fp);
        }

        private function detect_browser() 
        {
            $ua = strtolower($_SERVER['HTTP_USER_AGENT']);

            if(preg_match('/(chromium)[ \/]([\w.]+)/', $ua))
                $browser = 'chromium';
            elseif(preg_match('/(chrome)[ \/]([\w.]+)/', $ua))
                $browser = 'chrome';
            elseif(preg_match('/(safari)[ \/]([\w.]+)/', $ua))
                $browser = 'safari';
            elseif(preg_match('/(opera)[ \/]([\w.]+)/', $ua))
                $browser = 'opera';
            elseif(preg_match('/(msie)[ \/]([\w.]+)/', $ua))
                $browser = 'msie';
            elseif(preg_match('/(mozilla)[ \/]([\w.]+)/', $ua))
                $browser = 'mozilla';

            preg_match('/('.$browser.')[ \/]([\w]+)/', $ua, $version);

            return array('name'=>$browser,'version'=>$version[2]);
        }


        private function database_connect()
        {
            $con = mysql_connect(DB_HOST,DB_USER,DB_PASSWORD);
            if(!$con){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }
            $select = mysql_select_db(DB_NAME, $con);
            if (!$select){
                $this->log->logError(__FUNCTION__ . ' FAIL: ' . $query . ' BECAUSE: ' . mysql_error());
                return FALSE;
            }
        }       
    }

    $stats = new ThemeStatsTracker();
```

Comment: In my opinion, mysql is not the best way for storing logs, but it really depends on what you want to do with the logs further on. If you have alot of acceses on your application, this table could become hard to manage. Now, if you don't use this table for live queries, this will be fine in the future. But if you plan to, it can become a big problem.

Comment: Yes, well i am planning to use it for live queries, and i figured it might become a problem for instance, i currently have 600 users which have their own website, so it should be solid en fast enough to track a lot of traffic. Just updating the hit counter seems to work fine for 600 * 1000 users a day. But creating a new entry for every hit seems like a lost cause.

Comment: Are you planning to do queries on the user-agents textual values? If not, the current structure is good. If yes, then i would put all distinct user agent strings into a separate table, insert there only if you have a new one, if not, hold a reference to it in your original table. Hashing the UA string should help you with this, also the distinct UA strings table should be small enough to be manageable. But it all depends on what you plan to do with the information.

Comment: So i would make a table which already contains the UA i want to check, and then only update the attached userid's and hits? I don't get this part: _Hashing the UA string should_ could you elaborate?